# Batch editing metadata in Aperture

Tags: photos, aperture, metadata

In Aperture 3.2.2, is it possible to batch edit photos' metadata? For three days, my camera's clock was one year ahead but with the correct date, and I want to set them right all at the same time.

Comment: I don't want to use another program, but a plugin is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a batch adjustment of time and date, in Aperture under Metadata > Adjust Time and Date. From there you can specify an increment (one year back in your case) and all of th dates will be adjusted relatively. More information from the Aperture manual is [here](http://documentation.apple.com/en/aperture/usermanual/index.html#chapter=11&section=10&tasks=true).